# plt.figure() affecting kivy window?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, kivy

I'm trying to develop a kivy app for my less-comp-savvy colleagues which wraps a nice GUI around some computations which I developed for a project; currently the rather odd problem I'm having is that the plt.figure() function I'm calling to graph some data with in matplotlib.plotly is causing the kivy app window to shrink. Locking the size with Config.set() doesn't disinhibit this action. Any idea why this is happening? Odder thing still, the shrinking seems to increase the resolution of the kivy app such that the window is more crisp and easier to read, which is actually kind of nice. Just trying to understand what's going on here and how to work with it. Below is an example which recreates the phenomena.

--GUI.py--

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import threading
from calc import main


class Pop(Popup):
    pass


class MetaLevel(GridLayout):

    def dummy(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().pop.open()
        threading.Thread(target=self.calculate, args=(args,)).start()

    def calculate(self, *args):
        main()


class graphics(App):
    def build(self):
        self.pop = Pop()
        return MetaLevel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    graphics().run()
```

--calc.py--

```
def main():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from kivy.app import App
    from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool as Pool

    grid = np.array([(m, n)
                     for m in np.arange(1, 100, 1)
                     for n in np.arange(1, 100, 1)])

    def calc(grid):
        var1 = grid[0]
        var2 = grid[1]
        y = var1*var2
        return y

    res = Pool().map(calc, grid)

    fig = plt.figure(111, dpi=200)
    print('done')
    App.get_running_app().pop.dismiss()
    # data output from res here
```

--graphics.kv--

```
# Custom button
<Button>:
    font_size: 12

<MetaLevel>:
    id: calculator
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        height: 10
        Label:
            spacing: 10
            text: 'test'

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: run_button
            text: "Run"
            on_release: root.dummy()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something like the following might be happening:

- you have a high dpi display
- the kivy app is treating it as a low dpi display and letting the OS scale it up
- when matplotlib creates a window it requests a different config from the window manager (no stretching)
- the new config also applies to the Kivy window

I'm not sure exactly what the sequence of events would be, and this could actually arise from a bug somewhere, but it looks like a plausible reason for this to happen.

If this is the case, I don't know what the fix is. It would need some testing on the same OS with a comparable display setup. What OS are you using?

Comment: OS is Windows 10 home Vers. 1803 with OS build 17134.829; does the issue not replicate on (for example) your machine if you run the included code?

Comment: I haven't tried, I don't even use a window manager that lets windows set their own size. I suspect it wouldn't happen if I did, though.